# Frontend and backend resources

Tags: architecture, next.js, frontend, resources, backend

We're working on a small marketplace website. I am building the backend with Java and my colleague is building a frontend with next.js as a completely separate project. We are at a stage where we would like to deploy it and wire it up to see if thing are working. Now this is the part where neither of us really has too much experience.

At this point we are facing an issue. The backend is downloading data from various sources. Name, price, etc. are stored in a database but images were planned to be stored on the server. The trick is that next.js ideally should be deployed to Vercel as far as we know, but we have another hosting service for the backend. The images are frequently displayed on the frontend. I feel like sending the images constantly from backend is wrong. I wonder if:

- we should move the next.js to our hosting service instead of Vercel and set it up to have access to the same folder containing images. As I understand Vercel is good for static content anyway and ours is probably not really that;
- if there is a proper way to utilize Vercel;
- if there is another solution for example by utilizing some common (but secure) folder where both backend and frontend can access it;
- we messed it up somehow for example by next.js not being ideal for this kind of project;

I have tried to search but didn't really find any great results which makes me think that I probably don't know the right term for this kind of architectural issue.

Is there any best practice or common solution for this?

Comment: Pro tip: if you are unsure how an architecture will work, or using a new architecture for the first time, do a simple "hello world" working example that proves the architecture.  Look up the "steel thread" concept, e.g. https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.5555/2608547.2608553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the paths on the database and make use of one of the images optimizations built-in features by delegating that complexity to a CDN.

In the long-run the optimizations alone are a great benefit to your end-user due to the bandwidth saved and you having gone the custom route for a marketplace/e-commerce solution, they'll definitely benefit long-term conversions:

- [Image Optimization - Loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader)

> If you want to use a cloud provider to optimize images instead of
> using the Next.js' built-in Image Optimization, you can configure the
> loader and path prefix. This allows you to use relative urls for the
> Image src and automatically generate the correct absolute url for your
> provider.

Take a look at features and pricing of the cloud providers that you think better suit your project as a whole and go from there. All 3 included ones, as far as I know, are pretty solid.

If you wanted for a more custom route with a server of yours being in charge of the delivery (but not necessarily your backend server, i.e.: S3, Digital Ocean Spaces), I would start here instead:

- [CDN Support with Asset Prefix](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix)

Comment: I choose a CDN and did the implementation from backend, it seems to be working perfectly fine. Frontend is not yet done but I expect no issues there either. It turns out CDN also has some unexpected but nice additional functions for images. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

(Not unkindly:) You might be forgetting your client's runtime and how the web works.

All the users browser needs is the URL of the image - the image can come from anywhere.  The name/URL of the image can be in the database/backend even though its in a totally different place from where the images are.

Unless I'm missing something...?

Comment: You are right, I actually forgot that :) I was saving the public images in a restricted folder with some forms but I could have just changed the path and go with it.
I am unable to vote, yet and I went with CDN in the end as it seemed useful but you are right :)